# Query table and related table in Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have two tables set up in a database, a "Posts" table and an "Images" table. Rows in the Images table are related the Posts table with an ID so at any time there can be a single Post, but multiple rows from the Image table assigned to it. I don't want to run a join as it results in duplicate content from the Posts table when it adds the Posts to each row in Images

I'd like to be able to iterate through this content in the following manner:

```
foreach(posts as post)
{
    foreach(post['image'] as image)
    {
        // something here
    } 
}
```

In Django, this can be set up in my model through the following:

```
class Posts

    # something here

   def get_images(self):
       return self.images_set.select_related('post')
```

Is it possible to have a similar set up in a Codeigniter model using their Active Record? The only way I've been able to it was to query the Posts table, loop through results and query the Images table while inside the loop. Then set everything up as a new array and send it to the controller. But that doesn't seem efficient at all. Here's an example:

```
public function get_posts()
{
    // Grab all posts
    $query = $this->db->get('posts_table');
    $results = $query->result_array();

    // Arrays for storage
    $photoArray = array();
    $postsArray = array();
    $postsResultArray = array();

    $postsResultArray[] = $results;

    // Query photos in DB
    foreach($photoResultArray[0] as $row)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('uploads', array('tableName' => 'posts_table', 'recordNum' => $row['num'], 'fieldname' => 'images'));
        $results = $query->result_array();

        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            $photoArray[] = $row;
        }

    }

    // Associate each post with photo if available
    foreach($postsResultArray[0] as $post)
    {
        foreach($photoArray as $row)
        {
            if($row['recordNum'] == $post['num']) 
            {
                $post['image'] = $row['urlPath'];
            }
        }
        $postsArray[] = $post;
    }

    return $postArray;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try using a left join? how big are the tables?

Comment: Around 300 rows. I was avoiding using a join as I didn't want to end up with duplicate post rows when looping through the posts. Wouldn't individual rows from one table be duplicated if they are being related to multiple rows in another table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public function get_posts()
 {
     // Grab all posts
     $query = $this->db->get('images');
     $results = $query->result_array();

     // Arrays for storage
     $photoArray = array();
     $postsArray = array();

     $photoResultArray[] = $results;

     // Query photos in DB
     foreach($photoResultArray as $row)
     {
         $photoArray[$row->id] = $row->image;
     }

     $query2 = $this->db->get('posts');
     $results2 = $query2->result_array();
     $postsResultArray[] = $results2;

     // Associate each post with photo if available
     foreach($postsResultArray[0] as $post)
     {
         $postsArray[] = $photoArray[$post->image_id];
     }

     return $postArray;
 }
```